# react-native run-android, unimodules installling contains unused expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I recently `eject expo` from my react-native app and successful run the app after some configuration and code changes.

I already remove 'expo' from the `package.json` since I realize the current project has no use of any api from it. The only possible related package I used is `@expo/vector-icons`.

While testing the app through `react-native run-android` or inside `android` folder run `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` I have noticed the following the message.
[image]

Is this normal behaviors that those packages are installed. I just cannot figure out where and why those unimodules are installed.

I also remove

```
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
```

from `android\app\src\main\java\com\pedoer\MainApplication.java`. Not sure if this action will break my code in the future. But those are still installed after cleaning cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all included by default in react-native-unimodules: https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

You can exclude them as described under the "Need to exclude some unimodules that are being automatically linked?" headings in that same project README

Comment: I just go through the repo and found out by myself from  https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules/blob/master/index.js.

Comment: Fixed link to docs: https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/#-need-to-exclude-some-unimodules-that-1